# Сколько существует путей и почему?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Если шагающий начинает из точки (0, 0) и переходит в точку (50, 75) и имеет такое ограничение, что каждый шаг идет либо на одну единицу вверх,
либо на одну единицу вправо, сколько путей существует для такого ходуна... Сколько существует путей и почему?

Comment: вам математически формула нужна или программный алгоритм перебора?

Comment: Желательно просто описать, сколько путей и кратко почему, этого мне будет достаточно для дальнейшего саморазвитие :)

Comment: С(75, 50), если не ошибаюсь)) Потому что f(m, n) = f(m-1, n)+f(m, n-1) =)

Comment: @vp_arth, там же зеркальная ситуация во первых, а во вторых C(2, 2) = 1, а там 6 вариантов (ну или если убрать зеркальные - 3 варианта)

Comment: Ну или как там позиции в треугольнике паскаля обозначаются? =)

Comment: @vp_arth на самом деле C(50+75, 50) = C(50+75, 75)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно очень просто - движение по горизонтали - пишем 0, по вертикали - пишем 1. В итоге у нас каждый путь - число из 125 знаков, в котором 50 нулей и 75 единиц. В общем случае - M нулей и N единиц.

Чтобы определить количество таких чисел, надо прикинуть, сколькими способами можно выбрать N единиц среди N+M знакомест. Первая единица - N+M способов, вторая - N+M-1 и так далее... Итого - (N+M)!/M! Но еще надо поделить на N!, так как порядок всех этих единиц не играет роли. Очевидно, что то же значение получается, если рассматривать M нулей.

Итого всего таких путей -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, а само число - 249510749788530813877394729177487510